# why is my socket.io server assigning new socket ids to clients or losing track of existing socket ids?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, serversocket

I'm developing a simple website, where the client and server communicate over web sockets. I'm using nodejs and the [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/index.html) library for the socket communication

Specifically, my server works as a middleware between an mqtt broker and my client. So on one hand, my server connects with the mqtt broker to consume messages and on the other hand delivers these messages to the connected clients over web sockets. I'm using the node [mqtt library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) for the mqtt communication.

My codebase is fairly large, so to give you a feeling of how my code looks like, I will show this example, which should be straightforward to understand:

```
 const io = require("socket.io")(port);
 
  handleRequests(io) {
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      logger.info(`New client connected: ${socket.id}`);
      this.clients[socket.id] = { // track clients and subscribed topics
        topic: '', 
      };
      this.numberOfUsers++;
      io.sockets.emit("onUser", this.numberOfUsers);

      this.handleChange(socket);
      this.addToSubscribedClients(socket);
      this.removeFromSubscribedClients(socket);
      this.handleDisconnect(socket);
     this.sendMqttMessageToClient(socket);
      
    });     
  }
```

This is my "main" function, where as you can see, I'm initializing an io object and using it later by passing it to the handleRequests function. Each time a new client connects, I'm calling the callback function where I call the five other functions and passing the socket object as a parameter, which should be fine I guess. I'm passing the socket object as a parameter because I need it to later call `socket.emit` in order to send back message to a specific client, since the socket object is unique for each client.

This works great until more than ~ 30 clients are connected. I'm trying to debug this for 2 weeks now and can't figure out why this is happening. I'm testing this by opening multiple tabs in my browser. I start with one client and then increase the number of clients/tabs. At some points, I notice that some clients receive no values from the server but other clients still do, which is incorrect since all clients should receive the values in real time.

I noticed that the clients, which are not receiving values have other ids than the ones stored on the server. I tested this with a simple `console.log()` on both clients and server. How this is happening? I'm very positive that I'm sending the ids correctly since there are other clients, which still receive values from the server. My guess is that the server is somehow disconnecting some clients automatically, because if a client reconnects then a new id will be assigned to it automatically.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? and why it works fine with the first ~30 clients and starts to occur when many clients are connected? This issue is very hard to debug since the code works fine for a small number of clients and no errors are thrown when the bug occurs, so I'm hoping that someone had this before.

### Edit

Now I just found that i can print a reason for socket disconnection. When I do that, **`ping timeout`** is printed, which I don't understand because when I have one single or few clients connected then this error does not happen.